# How can I delay jQuery functions to wait for content to fadeOut?

Tags: javascript, jquery

There are six buttons in a grid, each containing a title (h3) and an image.

When one of the buttons is clicked, I'm using jquery to pull the content (title and image) from the selected button and display it (the same title and image) more prominently (with different styling) in a featured section nearby.

In order to make the interaction look/feel smooth, I've added a fadeOut() to the div containing the featured content before the featured content is changed and a fadeIn() after it is changed.

Problem is, the browser processes the commands faster than the featured content can fadeOut(). So it looks pretty bumpy.

In short, my code is written in this order:

1. Fade out featured section
2. Change featured content
3. Fade in with new featured content

But it's happening in this order:

1. Change featured content
2. Fade out featured section
3. Fade in with new featured content

Here's my code:

```
$('.obst-tile').click(function(){

    $(this).parent().children().removeClass('is-selected');
    $(this).addClass('is-selected');

    $('.obst-feature').fadeOut();

    var selectedId = $('.is-selected').attr('id');
    var imgLocation = $('#' + selectedId + ' img').attr('src');
    var featureTitle = $('#' + selectedId).find('h3').text();


$('.obst-featured-img').attr('src',imgLocation);
$('.obst-desc-headline').text(featureTitle);



    $('.obst-feature').fadeIn();




});
```

Everything works fine (the content updates properly when the button is clicked), so I'm not really looking for help debugging this or for recommendations on how I could do write this in a more concise way. Just trying to figure out how to delay the change of content long enough for the fadeOut to occur.

Thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$.fadeOut() has callback function;

```
$('.obst-tile').click(function(){

    $(this).parent().children().removeClass('is-selected');
    $(this).addClass('is-selected');

    $('.obst-feature').fadeOut(function(){

    var selectedId = $('.is-selected').attr('id');
    var imgLocation = $('#' + selectedId + ' img').attr('src');
    var featureTitle = $('#' + selectedId).find('h3').text();


$('.obst-featured-img').attr('src',imgLocation);
$('.obst-desc-headline').text(featureTitle);



    $('.obst-feature').fadeIn();

});


});
```